# REST route not working with Meteor's iron router

Tags: rest, meteor, iron-router

I'm trying to create a simple REST api in my Meteor app. Using the exact example from the [doc](http://iron-meteor.github.io/iron-router/#restful-routes)

```
Router.route('/webhooks/stripe', { where: 'server' })
.get(function () {
  // GET /webhooks/stripe
})
.post(function () {
  // POST /webhooks/stripe
})
.put(function () {
  // PUT /webhooks/stripe
})
```

throw an error:

```
=> Exited with code: 8
W20160116-16:39:15.200(-8)? (STDERR)          
W20160116-16:39:15.201(-8)? (STDERR) /Users/me/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.1.10.1b51q9m++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.osx.x86_64/dev_bundle/server-lib/node_modules/fibers/future.js:245
W20160116-16:39:15.201(-8)? (STDERR)                        throw(ex);
W20160116-16:39:15.201(-8)? (STDERR)                              ^
W20160116-16:39:15.204(-8)? (STDERR) TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'get'
W20160116-16:39:15.205(-8)? (STDERR)     at lib/router.js:9:4
W20160116-16:39:15.205(-8)? (STDERR)     at /Users/me/repo/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/app/lib/router.js:25:4
W20160116-16:39:15.205(-8)? (STDERR)     at /Users/me/repo/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/boot.js:242:10
W20160116-16:39:15.205(-8)? (STDERR)     at Array.forEach (native)
W20160116-16:39:15.205(-8)? (STDERR)     at Function._.each._.forEach (/Users/me/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.1.10.1b51q9m++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.osx.x86_64/dev_bundle/server-lib/node_modules/underscore/underscore.js:79:11)
W20160116-16:39:15.205(-8)? (STDERR)     at /Users/me/repo/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/boot.js:137:5
```

Any idea?

Comment: which version of iron-router are you using?

Comment: 0.9.4 and I'm trying to see why neither meteor update and meteor update iron:router upgrade it to the latest 1.0.12 version

Comment: I uninstalled and reinstalled and I'm now on 1.0.12 and things are working fine. You can post this as an answer and I'll accept it.
I had run `meteor update iron:router` previously but hadn't check the result... Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that you perhaps missed to install iron-router?

```
..     at /Users/me/repo/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/app/lib/router.js:25:4
```

This seems to indicate that `Router` is still the meteor own router, not iron-router, which lives somewhere in

```
/Users/me/repo/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/packages
```

Make sure you ran:

```
meteor add iron:router
```

You can see which packages are already installed using `meteor list`.

Comment: I do have iron:router. It's on the version 0.9.4 and I'm trying to see why neither `meteor update` and `meteor update iron:router` upgrade it to the latest 1.0.12 version